# Jenkins for C# Projects and Artefacts

Tags: c, jenkins, build, build-pipeline

after my last question about artefacts in an C# project, i´am using Nuget for my DLL´s, but with no "Snapshot" like system i use in Maven.

Are there any projects or tutorials about building an Build Pipeline with Jenkins as the Buildsystem and deploying Artefacts to an Artefact Server?

In our Java projects, i use Jenkins and Sonatype Nexus. Now i think i need Jenkins with msbuild and some kind of nuget server (atm it is just an file storage). Maybe, someone has done it already. I dont want to host an extra Team Foundation Server if i can avoid it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this Stackoverflow thread [setting-up-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-for-microsoft-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255898/setting-up-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-for-microsoft-applic/44265805#44265805).

They also have the Java stack established with Jenkins and Nexus and wants to reuse the same tools to setup the CI/CD process for their Microsoft.Net applications.